# Tomcat: setup realm for authentication to use Windows users

Tags: windows, tomcat, authentication

I'd like to setup Tomcat on Windows and have authentication in my web application be done against the Windows users (or a subset of those users). I read that if you have users setup on Active Directory, [you can use the JNDI realm](http://wiki.openi.org/index.php/Configuring_Tomcat_With_Active_Directory).

What if you don't have Active Directory, but just have "simple Windows users" setup on the server? Is it possible to setup a Tomcat realm to authenticate against those, or would I have to implement a realm that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the JAAS realm? [The realm documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/realm.html) refers to a "JAAS Realm (org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm)." JAAS is the Java Authentication and Authorization Service, which allows [pluggable authentication modules](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html). One of the default modules is [NTLoginModule](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/NTLoginModule.html), which sounds like it would do what you need.

Comment: I will be trying this out. Thank you for the suggestion.